# Can't open .biom file for Phyloseq tree plotting

Tags: r, bioinformatics, phylogeny

After trying to read a biom file:

```
rich_dense_biom  <-
  system.file("extdata", "D:\sample_otutable.biom", package = "phyloseq")

myData  <-
  import_biom(rich_dense_biom, treefilename, refseqfilename, parseFunction =
                parse_taxonomy_greengenes)
```

the following  errors are showing

```
Error in read_biom(biom_file = BIOMfilename) : 
  Both attempts to read input file:

either as JSON (BIOM-v1) or HDF5 (BIOM-v2).
Check file path, file name, file itself, then try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure *D:\sample_otutable.biom* really exists?  And is a system file?

In R for Windows, it is at least safer (if not required?) to separate file paths with `\\`

This works for me

```
library("devtools")
install_github("biom", "joey711")
library(biom)

biom.file <-
  "C:\\Users\\Mark Miller\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.3\\biom\\extdata\\min_dense_otu_table.biom"

my.data <- import_biom(BIOMfilename = biom.file)
```

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Since it worked, you could mark it answered, or give it an up-vote.